# 'PictureDetail' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: django

When I am **not logged in** and click on the **Download** link, this error appears.

*AttributeError at /pictures/5/
'PictureDetail' object has no attribute 'user'*

I want the picture to be downloaded only by the user who has at least one uploaded picture.

I could put **LoginRequiredMixin** as an attribute of the PictureDetail class and that would solve the problem, but I only need to hide the **Download** link and not the whole picture.

views.py

```
class PictureDetail(DetailView):
    model = Picture

    @login_required
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if Picture.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).exists():
            context["download"] = True
        return context
```

models.py

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

picture_detail.html

```
{% if download == True %}
<p class="card-text"><a href="{{ picture.picture.url }}">Download</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class PictureDetail(DetailView):
    model = Picture

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            if Picture.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).exists():
                context["download"] = True
        return context
```

Comment: This does not work, the request is underlined in red (name 'request' is not defined)

Comment: Yes, it should be self.request